# HashMap Mapped Value is slightly off

Tags: java, arrays, hashmap

The ArrayLists

```
This is jumblesOrdered: [act, aprt, art, dgo, fgor, opst]

This is jumbles: [arpt, atc, atr, gdo, grof, otsp]
```

Output:

```
This is jumbleWordHM: {opst=otsp, art=atr, fgor=grof, dgo=gdo, aprt=atc, act=arpt}
```

Code for HashMap:

```
        for (int i = 0; i < jumblesOrdered.size(); i++) {
        String word = jumbles.get(i);
        String sortedWord = jumblesOrdered.get(i);

        if (jumbleWordHM.get(sortedWord) == null) {
            jumbleWordHM.put(sortedWord, word);
        } else {
            jumbleWordHM.put(sortedWord, jumbleWordHM.get(sortedWord) + " "
                    + word);
        }

    }
```

My output for jumbleWordHM is slightly off. The output should be:

```
    This is jumbleWordHM: {opst=otsp, art=atr, fgor=grof, dgo=gdo, ****aprt=arpt, ****act=atc}
```

The **** indicates what needs to be switched.

Comment: Why do you have `act` first in jumblesOrdered and `arpt` first in jumbles?

Comment: jumblesOrdered is the alphabetical order of each letter in each String

Comment: `act` isn't how you put `arpt` in alphabetical order.

Answer (score 1):

Your first ArrayList starts with:

- [act, aprt,...

Your second ArrayList starts with:

- [arpt, atc,...

You're getting the elements in sequential order, so it's going to use the first element of the first list as a key and the first element of the second list as the value with the way you're putting them in the map.

If you're not guaranteed order you will need to add code to find the strings that contain the same letters.